# backup database PgAdmin 4 failed

Tags: sql, backup, pgadmin-4

Hi I was backing up the database on PgAdmin4 but I have this problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON9lw.png)

how can i solve?

Comment: Can you try resizing the dialog to see the logs ?

Comment: logs are not there, the box below is empty

Comment: In that case, the process itself must have not executed possibly because of some permission issues to write file or something.